# How can I grab multiple values that a user inputs and put them in a list without having to continuously write input()?

Tags: python, string, slice

I think if I know the answer to that question, I might be able to solve this. The code works with just one set of inputs. But if I input another set, it doesn't even acknowledge it. I think it would work if I hardcode another input() but is there a more dynamic way to capture the inputs?

> Mad Libs are activities that have a person provide various words,
> which are then used to complete a short story in unexpected (and
> hopefully funny) ways.
>
> Write a program that takes a string and an integer as input, and
> outputs a sentence using the input values as shown in the example
> below. The program repeats until the input string is quit and
> disregards the integer input that follows.
>
> Ex: If the input is:

```
apples 5

shoes 2

quit 0
```

> the output is:

Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.

Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.

My code:

```
UserEntered = input()


makeList = UserEntered.split()

get_item_1 = makeList[slice(0,1)][0]
get_item_2 = makeList[slice(1,2)][0]

if "quit" not in makeList:
    print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(get_item_2,get_item_1))
```

> 1: Compare output 0 / 5 Output differs. See highlights below.

Input

```
> apples 5 

> shoes 2 

>quit 0
```

> Your output:

```
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away. 

Expected output:

Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away. 

Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the code in your question, it accepts only ONE line of input. You need to write the whole block of code multiple times or you can utilize *looping* with `while` in python.

For example, the process you can do step by step is:

1. Set the looping and make it infinite unless it receives `quit`
2. Put the whole code block in the looping (`while True`) block.
3. Add the stopping condition, i.e. when it receives `quit 0`.

Here's the code for the steps above.

```
while True:    # Make an infinite loop.
    # Put the whole block to make sure it repeats
    makeList = UserEntered.split()
    get_item_1 = makeList[slice(0,1)][0]
    get_item_2 = makeList[slice(1,2)][0]
    
    # Print when the input is not `quit 0`
    if "quit" not in makeList:
        print("Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.".format(get_item_2,get_item_1))

    # Stopping control/condition here, when it receives `quit 0`
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I'll have to read up on (while True). I don't believe I've encountered that yet. I was so close. It's a shame I can't seem to do any of these tough problems without some help.